# Anyway to be able to push to heroku master with Procfile and requirments.txt in a seperate folder

Tags: git, heroku

If I have my `Procfile` and `requirements.txt` in the same folder as the file I am running everything works fine. But I am a "neat freak" and like to have everything in organized folders. Is there anyway to have those two files in a seperate folder and still be able to run `git push heroku master` with no errors?
Or is having them in the root dir the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible if using the official Python buildpack.

The detect script checks for a presence of `requirements.txt` (or `setup.py` or `Pipfile`), see https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/main/bin/detect

Procfile is required in the official Python buildpack.

---

Possible if you write your own Python buildpack.

You have to adjust the `detect` and `compile` to use your `requirements.txt` in a custom directory. Fork https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/tree/main/bin

The node buildpack does not require a `Procfile`. It executes `npm start` by default due to: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/main/bin/release

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# bin/release <build-dir>

cat << EOF
addons: []
default_process_types:
  web: npm start
EOF
```

For your custom buildpack you need to add something like that in your `release` script.

You can set a custom buildpack here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvYnm.png
It will show up here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz5Vd.png (Shellinabox is a custom buildpack)

Read more about buildpacks here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks